# QueryAsync DynamoDB with Index (Partition Key and Short Key) .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

Net Core project that using `DynamoDB`. They have `ScanAsync` and `QueryAsync`. I have no problem using `ScanAsync` but I read that the performance of Query is better so I want to use `QueryAsync` instead. I set up indexes with both Partition and Short Key. But I can only find the way to query with Partition key - not both.

Can someone help me with that?

For example I have a table called "Slot" with: Id, StaffId, WorkDate...which I created index with StaffId is Partition key and WorkDate is Short Key and the index called "StaffId-WorkDate-index"

[image]

Here is the only way I can find but can only use for "StaffId-index":

```
await QueryAsync<T>(StaffId, new DynamoDBOperationConfig { IndexName = "StaffId-index", ConsistentRead = false, QueryFilter = scanConditions }).GetRemainingAsync();
```

I expect I can using query for "StaffId-WorkDate-index". Thank you`enter code here`